# QTabWidget methods not available in QtDesigner

Tags: qt, pyqt4, qt-designer

One of the methods available in the `QTabWidget` class is [`setTabEnabled`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtabwidget.html#setTabEnabled) - I can't see of a way to set this in QtDesigner (I know I can set it in the code) - is there a specific reason why this method (and presumably others?) aren't settable in QtDesigner?

Comment: Only properties are visible in the property editor. This is currently not a property. You could submit a feature request [here](http://bugreports.qt-project.org/). [Read this](http://qt-project.org/wiki/ReportingBugsInQt#73ea5953d68b2c20a82bb94240f6fe17) if you want to know more about requesting features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've realised that there are two separate possible events:

- unchecking the 'enabled' checkbox for a tab widget in QtDesigner actually invokes `self.<tabname>.setEnabled(False)`, which seems to disable all child widgets within the tab, but does not disable the tab button itself(!)
- Disabling the tab button so that it's not clickable is not possible in QtDesigner, but is possible in code (as discussed in the previous answer): `self._uiform.<tab frame>.setTabEnabled(<tab index>,False)`

Answer (score 0):

Just change `enabled` property of respective widget inside `QTabWidget`.

---

according to documentation this suppose to work. I've taken a [look on `QTabWidget` code](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/57756e72adf2081137b97f0e689dd16c770d10b1%3asrc/gui/widgets/qtabwidget.cpp) and it looks like either documentation is wrong or there is a bug in code. I will not explain why just provide workaround on it.

Create this method:

```
void tabBarWorkaround(QTabWidget *tabWidget) {
    for (int i=0; i<tabWidget->count(); ++i) {
        tabWidget->setTabEnabled(i, tabWidget->widget(i)->isEnabled());
    }
}
```

And use it in construction time:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    tabBarWorkaround(ui->tabWidget);
}
```

From this moment changing `enabled` property of page in designer will work like you want.
I've test this with Qt 5.2.1 and it works.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the 'enabled' checkbox is for the parent `QWidget`, *not* each individual page widget; if you have a widget in the page, this has properties, but individual pages don't

Comment: @ChrisW you can select the tab pages in the object explorer on the right hand side

Comment: @ratchetfreak I believe he doesn't want to disable the tab widgets, but the tabs in the tab bar.

Comment: @thuga did you read the link doc in the OP? `setTabEnabled` sets the `enabled` property of the relevant tabWidgets.

Comment: @ratchetfreak It also disables the tab from the tab bar. `The page's tab is redrawn appropriately.`. Disabling the widget from the property editor does not do this.

Comment: @thuga you were correct in my assumptions about wanting the tab disabled on the tab bar.  Setting this manually in the code does work, and produces the effect I want.  Using the enabled checkbox in Qt Designer didn't achieve it - as you state, it does only disable the widget that the `page` is a child of